# How to check the BLE communication is still OK before writing to a characteristic

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use '[flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)' package to handle BLE connectivity in my app.

What is the best way to make sure the BLE write to a characteristic is possible before actually doing it?

Here is what I do for for now:

```dart
void sendCommand(String command) async {
    print("SDLTP: writing command [$command] thru BLE");

    const maxRetries = 3
    var retry = 0;
    do {
      try {
        retry++;
        await bleSdltpCommandCharacteristic.write(utf8.encode(command));
        break;
      } on PlatformException {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
      } catch (e) {
        print("Could not write on characterisics: $e");
      }
      // 3 retries to have a failsafe and avoid potential infinite loop
      // TODO: Check if we cannot have a 'real/decent' max retry...
    } while (retry < maxRetries);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check if a characteristic can be written is to write to the characteristic. Pre-flight checking would achieve nothing here. Even if a pre-flight passes, the subsequent write can still fail, so you need to handle that case anyway. Core Bluetooth already performs all possible pre-flight checks. If the CPeripheral is known to be disconnected, the `.state` value will be `.disconnected` and the CBCentralManagerDelegate method `centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)` will have been called. Other than "write a value and receive a response," there is no other way to know that a device can be written to.

If a BLE write fails, it is unlikely that an immediate retry will succeed, so this tight retry loop is unlikely to be helpful. In any case, 100ms is too short of a timeout for a BLE write. (Looking over the Flutter docs, I don't see any evidence this is a blocking call, anyway, so I'm not sure this attempt at timeouts is doing anything.)

Typically the existing retry/timeout logic of CoreBluetooth is correct. Trying to short-circuit and replace it this way is just fighting the system and likely to cause more problems for the device when you stack writes.

Comment: You’re probably right, hence the question. I removed the retry process anyway